# Can't get floating action button to appear if listview is not at the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make it so that a floating action button will appear if the user is not at the bottom of a listview, so that, when cicked, it will take the user to the bottom. But it's not really functioning as suspected. Here's the code-

Here _scrollController is my list view controller, and this is inside a Stateful Widget.

```
        floatingActionButton: _scrollController.position.pixels != _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent
            ? FloatingActionButton.small(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                    10,
                  ),
                ),
                backgroundColor: secondaryColor,
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward_outlined, color: Colors.white),
              )
            : null,
```

When I run this, it shows the floating action button, but when I get to the bottom, it doesn't disappear. This is most probably because the teranary operator is only getting called once. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you rebuilding your widget when you hit the bottom?

Comment: No, but thats where the problem arisrs. I need this same if statement to detect if the listview has hit the bottom

Comment: add a listener to your controller and trigger a rebuild when the condition is statisfied.

Comment: Something like this: `_scrollController.addListener(() { if(yourcondition) setState((){});}` put it in  `initState`

Comment: If that doesn't work, try to put a listener to the position parameter instead.

Comment: Adding the scroll controller listener makes it update everytime I scroll. Where do I add the listen to the position parameter?

Comment: Please check what I told you, add a listener but don't setState until the condition is satisified.

Comment: Oh yes sorry! I've got around everything, but another issue arose. When i'm using setState, the scroll goes back to the top. So this is clashing with everything